# Order of insert in android database

Tags: android, database, insert

I am wondering how can I insert an element at the beginning of the data base? I want to do this because:
a) I want to display the elements (ListView) as 'last-inserted on top and first-inserted on the bottom' (like a stack)
b) I want to limit the amount of elements in my db. When a new element is added (over the limit) I can put the new one (at the beginning) and delete the last one. (Don't know yet how to delete the last element).

I was searching for a solution but I am starting to wonder I have any control of how the element are inserted. If not I was thinking about displaying the database from end to bottom. But don't actually know how to do it since the cursor is always set at the beginning of the db. If could achieve this I can solve b) by deleting the first element (again don't know how to achieve this yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every row of every SQLite table has a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid"

To get last inserted at top and first inserted at bottom....

```
SELECT * from mytable order by ROWID desc;
```

Read more about ROWID [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

And, to delete the oldest:

```
DELETE from mytable WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM mytable);
```

If you use the ROWID, you do not have to modify your existing table. And, the value of ROWID is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I am getting the syntax error for the delete command you posted. I double checked and it is the same with my (putting mytabel name and marker for rowid column). Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Sytax for 'delete' in SQL is: DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value. So you need to put the FROM keyword before 'mytable'.

Comment: Ok there was missing 'from' after delete. It works thanks :> 

EDIT: Did not notice your comment antonyt :>

Comment: I have edited the delete syntax. Thanks to antonyt for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store a `timestamp` (as a new field) when you insert a record into your database. Then you delete the oldest record you can find if it is over the limit (e.g. using `MAX` SQL keyword). You can display the records in reverse-chronological order by sorting `DESC` with your `timestamp` field.