# How do I list entries in SQLite by the order they were added?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app I am writing that uses SQLite. I want the entries to be ordered by the date column, but if the dates are the same then I want them to be ordered by the order in which they were added (descending). This is what I have, which works for the first condition... Is there anyway to add the second without adding HH:MM:SS to the date entries?

SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY transactionDate DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ROWID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657565/477878) should do it;

```
SELECT * FROM transactions ORDER BY transactionDate DESC, ROWID DESC;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ccaa1/2).

Comment: Awesome, that worked - thanks! Also thank you for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using auto-assigned rowids you could just order them by those - that way you'd get them sorted correctly even if two entries were added in the same second.